# SQL Server - Updating multiple records joining with same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table price_info that contains the following columns:

```
group_id (int)    
product_id (int)
date (datetime)
price_override (money, nullable)
```

Some sample values:

```
group_id    product_id       date        price_override
   1             1        2014-02-10         25
   1             1        2014-02-11         30
   1             1        2014-02-12        NULL      
   1             2        2014-02-10         40
   1             2        2014-02-11         40
   1             2        2014-02-12         40
   1             3        2014-02-10        NULL
   1             3        2014-02-11        NULL
   1             3        2014-02-12        NULL
   2             1        2014-02-10         42
   2             1        2014-02-11         52
   2             1        2014-02-12         70
   2             2        2014-02-10         28
   2             2        2014-02-11         87
   2             2        2014-02-12         96
   2             3        2014-02-10         45
   2             3        2014-02-11         89
   2             3        2014-02-12        NULL
```

What I want to do is I want to update the price_override (and apply some calculations) of a product_id where the group_id and date are the same and the price_override is not null.

The calculation I want to do is multiply it by @ratio (float) and add @offset (float)

For example, for group_id 1, product_id 3, I want to set it's price_override to be the (price_override * @ratio) + @offset of group_id 1, product_id 2 (where its price_override is not null).

I've tried searching, but so far everything I've found is based on updating only 1 row using unique ids.

As per the requested edit, to update a single row given the values would be the following:

```
update price_info set price_override = @value where group_id = @group_id and product_id = @product_id and date = @date
```

Comment: Just write your where clause to select all eligible rows, as specified in your first paragraph, and the set statement to perform the calculation from the second paragraph. The rest of the update statement will be the same syntax as a single row update.

Comment: Please show what you've tried that did not work as you wanted it to.  What is the formula you would use to update a single row?  Also, where are these variables coming from and are they the same for all rows?

Comment: I've added the query for updating a single row.  I don't know the syntax for updating multiple rows like I need to, and I haven't found anything to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,

```
update price_info
set price_override = ((price_override * @ratio) + @offset)
where (group_id = 1) and ([DATE] = '2/10/14') and (price_override is not null)
```

might do what you want.